# custom HTML in search form ( site/search)

Tags: search

I'm trying to customize the html of the search block form.
I know that I can use templates.php to modifiy the fields and customize it but I'm trying here to change the whole html block.
I've tried to use search-form-block.tpl.php, but it didn't work (yes I've cleared cache).

I guess I'm missing something here ...

Any help appreciated thanks !

Ps : I'm using solr in an acquia environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hook_form_alter and use render API to alter the html attributes. You can add attributes such as class, id, wrapper tags(prefix and suffix), attaching css and js file to the rendered form this way too. It would be something like this.

```
function yourMod_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 if(strstr($form['#form_id'], 'search_form')) {
   $form['#attributes'] = array(
    'class'=> array('search-form-custom-class'),
    'id' => array(),
    );
   $form['#attached'] => array(
     'css' => array( drupal_get_path('module', 'yourMod') . '/css/yourMod.css' ),
   );
   $form['#prefix'] = "<div class='wrapper-for-search'>";
   $form['#suffix'] ="</div>";
 }
}
```

I advise to read more on the render API to see all attributes that you can alter.

Comment: Actually when you use solr the correct form_id to test is apachesolr_search_custom_page_search_form

Comment: That's useful to know. I wasn't sure what the form_id is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) in template.php.

Like

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
if($form_id=='search_form')
{
 // change values in $form.
}
}
```

Comment: Yes I know that but I can't change the html block through this function, right ?

Comment: You can use #prefix,#suffix in it..and can add id for search field